# UndefinedError when trying to call function in Jinja templaet

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my view function, I pass a dict variable to my HTML file.  `tags` is a dictionary which is by default `{int: []}`.  As the value of each key is a list, I use `iteritems()` to show every item in the list.  However, it didn't work, I got the error `UndefinedError: 'tags' is undefined`.  Is Jinja2 able to call functions in HTML?  Why didn't my code work?

```
return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, posts=posts, tags=tags)
```

```httml
<div class="post-tag">
{% for key,tag in tags.iteritems() %}
<a href="#">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I've never used flask but I've used jinja2 with cherrypy. Actually your code is absolutely correct. This is how it works but what I think is happening is that the variable `tags` is not defined when you are rendering the template. Have a look [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures)

All the basic datatype operations are available in jinja2. Check if `tags` is not being defined in some if condition that you're not entering in your particular case.

```
{% for k, v in dct.iteritems() %}<a href="#">{{k}}</a>{% endfor %}
```

outputs

```
<a href="#">item1</a><a href="#">item2</a>
```

Comment: I find that the dict variable is not passed to the html successfully and I've solved the problem.